# SSIS temporary Staging tables

Tags: ssis

Data flow task> ole DB Source1, ole DB Source2 > Union All > Ole DB Destination(table).

Instead of pushing the dataset/resultset into Ole DB Destination, can i hold the dataset/resultset somewhere temporarily and reference** the dataset later.

reference**: Meaning write sql based on that resultset/dataset.

Is that even possible. Let me know.

Note: 2 Ole DB Sources (both has different connections, different servers but both are MSSQl if that matters).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some sort of temp table on your SQL Server to do such kind of a thing. The record set destination does not support SQL'ised statements. On the lookup transformation, you can modify the SQL Query in the advanced editor tab (partial and full cache mode only).

Comment: That didn't answer my question whole lot but i dont think there is any better to do it. thx for looking into it though